# Не могу запустить приложение на хостинге через putty по SSH

Tags: ssh, putty

При попытке запустить приложение на сервере через пути выдается следующая ошибка :Server was not able to start with error message [Could not bind to tcp://0.0.0.0                                                                                        :135: Permission denied]

Most likely the port [135] you are trying to run the system is already taken by                                                                                         some other service.
Please find available free port and configure it in [config.php] and restart.
Хотя согласно ,если верить команды netstat -a он открыт и брандмауере добавлен в список исключений.
Скрины прилалагаю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы приложение запускаете из под привилегированного пользователя? Нужны права, чтобы занять порт ниже 1024.

Comment: спасибо за ответ,а как это сделать? И выше если порты использовать такая же ситуация